# Update application from server location

Tags: c#, deployment, vsto, outlook-addin, clickonce

I'm programming a VSTO add-in I would like to make "update-able" from the server where I publish.

[image]

Does ClickOnce permits that type of deployment or do I need to do it by myself?

This was possible using dropbox but not anymore :

[I need people's opinion on how to update a ClickOnce application through FTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095482/i-need-peoples-opinion-on-how-to-update-a-clickonce-application-through-ftp)

[DropBox public folder changes](https://help.dropbox.com/fr-fr/files-folders/share/public-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, ClickOnce can do what you are describing. You just need to choose a ClickOnce strategy and the update intervals, refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/choosing-a-clickonce-update-strategy?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Have you ever used ClickOnce on a server? I have no troublesd distributing by file transfer but can understand how to do it by publishing on a server...

Comment: Yes sure - you just need to put it on a web server. When you create your manifest ensure you put your url as the `Start Location` and then provide your users with the URL to install your application. You must give them, the full path of the deployment manifest. For example, if YourApp is deployed to http://webserver.com/ in the YourApp directory, the full path would be http://webserver.com/YourApp/YourApp.application

Comment: Here is a step by step guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/walkthrough-manually-deploying-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2019